# Can't copy PDF files at Documents folder in my Android 10 device

Tags: java, android

I want to copy PDF files in the Documents folder of a Android device. My phone, where I test the app is Android 10. I tried to get the path of Documents folder by this code:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF");
```

When I try to copy the PDF files in the app's private directory, it was working, but when I try to copy the PDF files in Documents folder, then I'm facing problem.

And I use below method to copy PDF.

```
public static void copyPDF(Context context, Uri pdfUri, String bookName) {
    try {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF");
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        InputStream inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(pdfUri);

        if (inputStream != null) {
            File outputFile = new File(dir, bookName + ".pdf");
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I ask for permission this way:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == READ_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Read Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Read Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == WRITE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Write Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Write Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void askForPermissions() {
    // read permission
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // write permission
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And here is my manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
```

What is the problem that there isn't a copy of PDF files in the Documents folder?

Answer (score 1):

Please note, after **API 30** `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is of no use and *simply ignored and does not grant anything*. Latest API (as of Dec 2023) way of doing this:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> importFileIntent;

importFileIntent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument(), new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(Uri returnData) {
        if(returnData != null) {
            Cursor pathData = getContentResolver().query(returnData, null, null, null, null);
            int nameIndex = pathData.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
            // int lengthIndex = pathData.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
            pathData.moveToFirst();
            String fname = pathData.getString(nameIndex);
            pathData.close();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(returnData);
                File importitem = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + fname);
                if(!importitem.exists()) {
                    Files.copy(inputStream, importitem.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    inputStream.close();
                } else {
                    // File already exists...
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
});
String[] in = {"*/*"};
importFileIntent.launch(in);
```

I'm on my phone and have messed up the indentation...
Only the critical excerpts we provided. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I got this error: `LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.` at the line of registerForActivityResult(...)

Comment: have you placed the code section within the ```onCreate(...)``` method of your Activity?

Comment: I implement your code in an `onClickListener` and the onClickListener is in the `onCreate()` method. I want to copy files when a button is clicked, that's why I implement the code in an onClickListener.

Comment: no, the construction portion should be the immediate child of ```onCreate(...)``` only. it is the _calling_ of it (last 2 lines) that you can put within some listener or handler. the object must be created/exist on the Activity level.

Comment: I wrote that code in `onCreate()`. And I change `importitem` to this: `File importitem = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF/" + fname);` and I got this error: `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/PDF/pdf_name.pdf`

Comment: well, this would mean there is no such file name ```pdf_name.pdf``` right?

Comment: the code should display the SAF and you should pick a file. __That__ file is _imported_ (copied) into your app's own assigned directory, where now you can manipulate this file however you want to. that is the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I've solved the problem in a different way.

Comment: good to know. but keep this solution in a file somewhere as well. this is the classic import pattern that will surely come in handy some day. good luck!